# Array of IDs to array of function results

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

I currently have this code

```
def objects(ids)
  array = []

  ids.each do |id|
    array << object(id) # => #<object[id]>
  end

  array
end

objects([1, 2, 3])
# => [#<object1>, #<object2>, #<object3>]
```

It seems like there should be a cleaner way to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
This is what works

```
[1, 2, 3].map do |id|
  object(id)
end
```

**ORIGINAL**
go this way:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:object_id)
# => [3, 5, 7]

def objects(ids)
  ids.map(&:object_id)
end

objects([1, 2, 3])
# => [3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: For this, what are you assuming is the the "object_id?". Inside of my `object()` I search through an array to match an ID and then format a hash from the result.